# How to make lodash import in JSBin?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, jsbin

I need to show one code in JSBin with the lodash and cannot figure it out how to make a 'get' import. I've got `"ReferenceError: require is not defined`
https://jsbin.com/hotobir/edit?js,console

```
// Normally that is working fine
import { get } from 'lodash'

//No import get from 'lodash/get'
//No const { get } = lodash

const obj = { myKey: 'myValue' }
console.log(get(obj, 'myKey', 'notThere'))
```

How to do this import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the JSBin drop the script import in the wrong place. It shoul to be in the head of html.

```
const {get} = _
const obj = { myKey: 'myValue' }
console.log(get(obj, 'myKey', 'notThere'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the `Add Library` option doesn't work the way I expected either.

It prepends the script tag to the html output, so if you don't make any changes it doesn't work.

[image]

**Solution**: just move the script tag into the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

To add any library in jsbin place the cursor inside head of the html, add the lib, and make sure you add the language='javascript' in the `<script` tag. That way works for me at least.

Eg. From this:

```
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"> 
  </script>
```

To this:

```
  <script
    language='javascript'
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"> 
  </script>
```